# Howto create a nested/conditional option with optparse-applicative?

Tags: haskell, applicative, optparse-applicative

Is possible to create a haskell expression, using the methods in [optparse-applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative), that parses program options like this?

```
program [-a [-b]] ...
```

**-a** and **-b** are optionals flags (implemented using `switch`), with the constraint that the **-b** option only is valid if **-a** is typed before.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is possible, with slight tweaks, two different ways:

1. You can make a parser that only allows `-b` if you've got `-a`, but you can't insist then that the `-a` comes first, since optparse-applicative's `<*>` combinator doesn't specify an order.
2. You can insist that the `-b` option follows the `a` option, but you do this by implementing `a` as a command, so you lose the `-` in front of it.

Applicative is definitely strong enough for this, since there's no need to inspect the values returned by the parsers to determine whether `-b` is allowed, so `>>=` is not necessary; If `-a` succeeds with *any* output, `-b` is allowed.

### Examples

I'll use a data type to represent which arguments are present, but in reality these would be more meaningful.

```
import Options.Applicative

data A = A (Maybe B)   deriving Show 
data B = B             deriving Show
```

So the options to our program maybe contain an A, which might have a B, and always have a string.

```
boption :: Parser (Maybe B)
boption = flag Nothing (Just B) (short 'b')
```

### Way 1: standard combinators - `-b` can only come with `-a` (any order)

I'll use `flag' () (short 'a')` which just insists that `-a` is there, but then use `*>` instead of `<*>` to ignore the return value `()` and just return whatever the `boption` parser returns, giving options `-a [-b]`. I'll then tag that with `A :: Maybe B -> A` and finally I'll make the whole thing `optional`, so you have options `[-a [-b]]`

```
aoption :: Parser (Maybe A)
aoption = optional $ A <$> (flag' () (short 'a' ) *> boption)

main = execParser (info (helper <*> aoption) 
                        (fullDesc <> progDesc "-b is only valid with -a")) 
        >>= print
```

Notice that since `<*>` allows any order, we can put `-a` after `-b` (which isn't quite what you asked for, but works OK and makes sense for some applications).

```
ghci> :main -a 
Just (A Nothing)
ghci> :main -a -b
Just (A (Just B))
ghci> :main -b -a
Just (A (Just B))
ghci> :main -b
Usage: <interactive> [-a] [-b]
  -b is only valid with -a
*** Exception: ExitFailure 1
```

### Way 2: command subparser - `-b` can only follow `a`

You can use `command` to make a `subparser` which is only valid when the command string is present. You can use it to handle arguments like cabal does, so that `cabal install` and `cabal update` have completely different options. Since `command` takes a `ParserInfo` argument, any parser you can give to `execParser` can be used, so you can actually nest commands arbitrarily deeply. Sadly, commands can't start with `-`, so it'll be `program [a [-b]] ...` instead of `program [-a [-b]] ...`.

```
acommand :: Parser A
acommand = subparser $ command "a" (info (A <$> (helper <*> boption)) 
                                         (progDesc "you can '-b' if you like with 'a'"))

main = execParser (info (helper <*> optional acommand) fullDesc) >>= print
```

Which runs like this:

```
ghci> :main 
Nothing
ghci> :main a 
Just (A Nothing)
ghci> :main a -b
Just (A (Just B))
ghci> :main -b a
Usage: <interactive> [COMMAND]
*** Exception: ExitFailure 1
```

So you have to precede `-b` with `a`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you can't. This is precisely the scenario that `Applicative` alone can't handle while `Monad` can: changing the *structure* of later actions based on earlier results. In an applicative computation, the "shape" always needs to be known beforehand; this has some advantages (like speeding up so array combinations, or giving out a nice readable help screen for command-line options), but here it limits you to parsing "flat" options.

The interface of optparse-applicative also has `Alternative` though, which does allow dependent parsing, albeit in a different way as shown by AndrewC.

Comment: Are you sure? We _do_ know this structure beforehand, it's just nested. Couldn't you use `command` on __a__ and use the subparser to implement __b__?

Comment: It's fixed, but not Applicative. You could include some static branching behavior by adding a type like `f Bool -> (Bool -> f r) -> f r`, i.e. a type restrained `(>>=)`.

Comment: Sorry, @leftaroundabout, but I cannot agree with your reasoning. Applicative is strong enough for this kind of thing, otherwise we wouldn't be able to use the applicative interface to parsec to allow = to only appear after an identifier. You don't need to check the text of the identifier to know that = can follow it, so you don't need bind. Similarly here, you can parse -a and return (), (not the letter a). You don't need to inspect the value () to know that -b is now allowed, so you don't need bind. The problem is purely that in this context, <*> is non-deterministic about order.

Comment: @AndrewC: the problem is that "implemented using `switch`" does imply that we need to "inspect" the boolean value to know whether `-b` will be allowed; that's what applicatives can't do which is the point of my answer. You can certainly get a solution with other tricks, as shown in your answer, but you're not really using the applicative interface then but built-in higher order functions. The only straightforward and all-purpose solution would be a monad (or at least arrow) interface.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'm using completely standard Applicative & Alternative combinators in my first method, just on top of a non-optional flag' (`optional` is from Alternative). I took "implemented using switch" to mean "currently implemented using switch". Can we agree to "I'm afraid you can't if you stick to using `switch`"? The reason I'm concerned is that as currently written it implies that Applicative is an extremely weak interface for parsing, which it isn't.

Comment: `Applicative` _is_ an extremely weak interface. But yeah, `Alternative` is reasonably powerful; frankly I overlooked that instance.